# can we do in mysql a select query that order by date and add anything that expire current date on the bottom of the query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table example:

table name **SHOW** with 3 column ( `id, title, representationDate`).

I want to select all show and place it in order of date with `distinct title` because I can have the same `title` but at different `representationDate`. I want also that when I do my select query that any expire show be in the bottom of my list and all none expire show at the top by order of `representationDate`.

Right now I try this but don't give me the result I want.

```
SELECT distinct title as title
FROM SHOW
WHERE id = 23
AND representationDate > NOW()
UNION
(SELECT distinct title as title
FROM SHOW
WHERE id = 23
AND representationDate < NOW()
ORDER BY representationDate ASC)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why do you specify the id? This means you'll get only one result. I would use `SELECT distinct title as title FROM SHOW WHERE representationDate > NOW() UNION (SELECT distinct title as title FROM SHOW representationDate < NOW() ORDER BY  representationDate ASC)`

Comment: that my error i use inner join from another table that give a list of title and representation forgot to remove the id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you obviously have encountered it that with unions you can order any particular parenthesized SELECT statement, but when performing the UNION across the results of the individual SELECT's, order is not guaranteed, so you could have interleaved results.  You can order the overall UNIONed result set (outside of parenthesis at the end), but this will not get you what you are looking for as this would not allow you to differentiate expired records from non-expired records.

What you might want to do is to generate a calculated field by which you can sort:

```
SELECT
    distinct title,
    (CASE when representationDate >= NOW() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE) as `current`
FROM SHOW
WHERE id = 23
ORDER BY `current` DESC, representationDate ASC
```

Comment: it work thanks appreciate your help but can we hide current from select since my query need only title to appear???

Comment: @DarkVision Just don't use the field in your application.

Comment: well i need the case but i dont want it to appear in my result since my query need only the title when the query call

Comment: @DarkVision Again, just because a field exists in your result set, doesn't mean the application that is making the query needs to do anything with it. If this is really a sticking point for you, you might be able to nest this select as a subquery in a select that struip out this field - `SELECT title FROM (SELECT ... ) as temp`.  Though this seems kind of silly.

Comment: Appreciate for your help your right i will change my result set so i take only the title.

Comment: @DarkVision I would actually think that that flag could potentiall be useful in the application itself.  Say for example you want to change the way expired/non-expired records are displayed, you could use that field value to dynamically control display properties rather than having to recalculate expiration status in the application logic.